# Using rspec-spies `have_received` matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake, matcher

Looking at [this blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/11957424161/test-rake-tasks-like-a-boss), I'm trying to set up my ability to use the matcher `Object.should have_received(:action).with(*params)` and can't seem to get it. To break things down, I wrote a really really simple rake task:

```
# lib/tasks/check_log.rake
namespace :check_log do
  # other tasks omitted

  desc "Task description"
  task :test => :environment do
    ImportRecording.log.debug "Something"
  end
end
```

And here's the test I've written for it under `spec/lib/tasks/check_log_rake_spec.rb`

```
require_relative '../../support/shared_contexts/rake'
# other requirements omitted
describe "check_log:test", focus: true do
  include_context "rake"

  let(:log_name) { "import.log" }
  let(:checker) { CheckLog.new log_name }
  let(:import_log) { ImportRecording.log }
  let(:message) { "Asterisk import finished!" }

  it "verify a method was called on a log" do
    subject.invoke
    ImportRecording.log.should have_received(:debug).with("Something")
  end
end
```

Courtesy of the aforementioned blog post, here's my shared context, under `spec/support/shared_contexts/rake.rb`

```
require "rake"

shared_context "rake" do
  let(:rake)      { Rake::Application.new }
  let(:task_name) { self.class.top_level_description }
  let(:task_path) { "lib/tasks/#{task_name.split(":").first}" }
  subject         { rake[task_name] }

  def loaded_files_excluding_current_rake_file
    $".reject {|file| file == Rails.root.join("#{task_path}.rake").to_s }
  end

  before do
    Rake.application = rake
    Rake.application.rake_require(task_path,[Rails.root.to_s],loaded_files_excluding_current_rake_file)

    Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
  end
end
```

So I installed the `rspec-spies` gem and added the following line to my `spec_helper`

```
require `rspec-spies`
```

But when I run the test, I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: ImportRecording.log.should have_received(:debug).with("Something")
   expected #<Logger:0x007ffbbe4638b0 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007ffbbe463108 @datetime_format=nil>,
   @formatter=#<Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x007ffbbe462960 @datetime_format="%F %T">,
   @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x007ffbbe462f28 @shift_size=1048576, @shift_age=0,
   @filename="/Users/brad/code/ruby/rails_projects/rl4/log/import.log",
   @dev=#<File:/Users/brad/code/ruby/rails_projects/rl4/log/import.log>,
   @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x007ffbbe462e60 @mon_owner=nil,
   @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x007ffbbe462af0>>>,
   @mock_proxy=#<RSpec::Mocks::Proxy:0x007ffbbae76a68 @object=#<Logger:0x007ffbbe4638b0 ...>,
   @name=nil, @error_generator=#<RSpec::Mocks::ErrorGenerator:0x007ffbbae76a18 @declared_as="Mock",
   @target=#<Logger:0x007ffbbe4638b0 ...>, @name=nil>,
   @expectation_ordering=#<RSpec::Mocks::OrderGroup:0x007ffbbae769c8 @ordering=[]>,
   @messages_received=[], @options={}, @already_proxied_respond_to=false,
   @null_object=false>> to have received :debug with ["Something"]
```

However, I've verified the line is being written. Am I using the method incorrectly or can someone point in the right direction here?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourne), I was misunderstanding test-spies. They are in fact a 2-step process, one in which you must

1. Stub the method you expect to be called
2. Call the overlying method or process
3. Use the `have_received` matcher to verify what was stubbed was actually called

Making these changes to my tests have fixed all my problems.